# doing calculations inside jsx in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing this problem where I want to do calculation inside jsx in reactjs .
I can do this inside render and do it easily but I want to do it isnide jsx .

```
{
  flag === true ? (
    <div className={classes.statement}>
      <p>  Rs {10000*{adsobject.state && adsobject.state.home && adsobject.state.home.rate}}</p>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className={classes.statement}>
      <p>Rs {10000*{adsobject.state && adsobject.state.away && adsobject.state.away.rate}}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here I just want to multiply 100000 with the data I am getting .

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace the nested curly braces `{}` with round brackets `()`

```
<p>Rs {10000*(adsobject.state && adsobject.state.home && adsobject.state.home.rate)}</p>
```

`{}` is used to insert expression inside jsx. You just need to write a normal Javascript expression inside it